# Using PHP include to include a file with it's own included file

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I am trying to load a projects.php file into a higher-level index.php file and want to maintain all the .js .css and any further nested (in .js files) .php files, that are declared in the projects.php file.

My index.php file goes like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>BLST</title>
</head>

<body>
    <?php $projectsPage = "/tables/php/projects.php"?>
    <li><a href="index.php?page=<?php echo $projectsPage;?>">Projects</a></li>
    <?php if(is_null($_GET["page"])) { 
                $page = ""; 
        }else{ 
            $page = $_GET["page"]; 
        } 
       include($page); 
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

My projects.php file is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

        <title>Projects</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            @import "css/test.css";
            @import "http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.23/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css";
        </style>

        <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" charset="utf-8" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
```

The issue is that none of the files in projects.php are found. This is because the browser is looking to my main directory now (where index.php is).

Comment: The js should be called. Ill need to see a little more, like the generated code or a live example or more code ;P

Comment: It should work. Does those includes appear in page's source?

Comment: Why wouldn't it work? Worked perfectly well for me. You may want to add a closing semi-colon `<?php include "stuff.php"; ?>` but I doubt it; both worked.

Comment: If I load /php/stuff.php, everything works. I have a few js files (that are using AJAX and calling further nested php files). But if I load /php/stuff.php into index.php (which is about 5 levels up) basically every php, js and css link is broken in stuff.php.

Comment: Try omitting all closing `?>` tags then; they're not really required 95% of the time.

Comment: If you using ajax to call the PHP file, then just add the js to the DOM with javascript. That way its loaded before the DOM objects appear.

Comment: I;ve updated my question maybe it makes more sense now.

Comment: It should work. I don't know why it's not working for you.

Comment: I think I know what the problem is. You're using an absolute path `<?php $projectsPage = "/tables/php/projects.php"?>` which 9 times out of 10 does not work. If you're going to want to use that, either use `/var/user/html/tables/php/projects.php` or use a relative path `<?php $projectsPage = "tables/php/projects.php"?>` or `<?php $projectsPage = "../tables/php/projects.php"?>`

Comment: No, those make no difference. My projects.php file is still looking for all its includes as if it was the index.php file. For example, "test.css" for the projects.php page is in tables/php/css/test.css" so when I include projects.php in index.php, it thinks oh, website.com/css/test.css

Comment: Well, I don't know what else to say that will be of further help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The test.css is in "tables/php/css/test.css" and what about the location of projects.php and index.php.

I think the answer to these will solve the problem.

Comment: I know where the files are, I need to know how to point my index.php to them.

Comment: Yes that is what you have to tell me as to where these files are located so that I could help you out.

Comment: Okay let's say: "htdocs/index.php", "htdocs/tables/php/projects.php", "htrocs/tables/php/css/test.css", "htdocs/tables/php/js/jquery.min.js" etc

Comment: Alright in that case try giving the path for test.css as '/tables/php/css/test.css' in projects.php and see if it works. Similarly do the same for jquery.min.js. Try this and let me know.